# What is the correct way to center a text in a DIV button

Tags: css, coding-style

I've always wondered what the 'best' way to position text inside a div is

1) Put padding on the element surrounding the text and minus the padding from the height/width of the element.

```
<div class="button">
    Activate
</div><!-- button -->

.button
{
    height: 20px;   /* -10px from padding for text */
    width: 90px;    /* -10px from padding for text */
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px; 
}
```

2) Put a span around the text, and position it as its own element.

```
<div class="button2">
    <span class="button2-text">
        Activate
    </span>
</div><!-- button2 -->

.button2
{
    height: 30px
    width: 100px
}
.button2-text
{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

I always go with 1) because its less code, but I feel 2) is more proper or something Wondering if I'm in the wrong for using method 1) in any way.

Comment: Padding is *included* in a block element's dimensions, so applying padding does not make the element bigger. Therefore, you should not decrease the height and width when padding is applied.

Comment: No, it is not included. Not unless you use `box-sizing: border-box;`. 1) is the method I would prefer. 2) means too much useless markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second option doesn't mix the height / width with the padding.

Nowadays browsers all follow the same box model (which is how you position in option 1). This is equivalent to having `box-sizing: content-box`.

Internet Explorer versions up to 6 and Quirks mode didn't and used the alternative one which included padding as part of the width, equivalent to `box-sizing: border-box`.

In order to correctly position for both models, using option 2 is the safest.

If you check http://jsfiddle.net/stb5a/ , `box-sizing` is set to `content-box`. Changing it to `border-box` doesn't change the positioning of the text;

So basically, option 2 would be used for compatibility with older versions of Internet Explorer (now pretty much gone) and by developers who use to code for these versions, using the same pattern as they've always done.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the `<button>`

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/isehij/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
<button class="button">Activate</button>
```

CSS:

```
  .button{
    border: 1px solid #888;
    background:#eee;
    padding:5px 30px;
    border-radius:4px;
  }
```

And you'll have free time to play with colors :)

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with 1) . In 2) the `<span>` tag is semantically useless. Unless you have no other content inside the `<div>` dont compliate your markup.

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) - Keep It Simple Stupid